# In Javascript JQuery, how to wait for a modal to close in a for loop before continuing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a situation where I need to do the following:

- Run through a loop for all values in an object that matches a string.
  ( That's easy enough )
- Then, once that string is matched, throw up a modal on screen that
  asks for input.
- **Wait for the modal to be closed, change an object value then continue
  on to the next in loop. If there's another object that matches this
  value, open a new modal and repeat.**
- Once the for loop is over, send the data via an ajax post call.

The issue I'm having is to wait for the modal to be closed and the value to be updated before continuing on. Since I don't want all modals to show up at the same time. I need to pause it when the modal is shown, resume it when the modal is hidden.

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultCustom.length; i++) {
if (resultCustom[i].Value == "Ask_User") {
    $('#ModalAsk').modal('show').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // do something...
    })
    break;

  }
}
$.post('@Url.Action("UpdateAction","Home")', resultCustom).done(function(data){
        player = data.player;
        load()
    });
// What is below is inside my modal as the onclick function for my submit button.
function SubmitAsk(i) {
    $('#ModalAsk').modal('hide')
    var input = document.getElementById("userinput").value
    resultCustom[i].Value = input
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute `$.map()` for `for` loop, `.one()` for `.on()` and utilize `.queue()`, `.promise()` and  `.then()` to achieve the expected result.

```
$({}).queue("wait", $.map(resultCustom, function(value, index) {
  return function(next) {
    // do stuff
    if (value.Value == "Ask_User") {
      $('#ModalAsk').modal('show').one('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // do something...
        next()
      })
    }

  }
}))
.dequeue("wait")
.promise("wait")
.then(function() {
  // done
})
```

Comment: How do I wait for the modal to be closed in this?

Comment: @MathiasChartier Is there an event dispatched when the modal is closed?

Comment: @MathiasChartier `hidden.bs.modal` or `hide.bs.modal` [Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)